# Only a part of css file doesn't work

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I'm new to js and I was following a tutorial to learn about node.js.
I used middleware and tried to adapt my css file into pages. But only a part of css file doesn't work even though I just copied and moved the whole style part from html file to css file.

Here is my `style.css`.

```
<style type="">
body {
    background: skyblue;
    font-family: verdana;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
p, li {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And only `background: skyblue` this part doesn't work.

The part I handle with static files is just like this.
`app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'))`

All other styles does work and I have no idea what is the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<style type="">` from your CSS. That's HTML, not CSS.

Comment: Sorry it's dumb mistake. I just removed and it works completely. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The skyblue color is equal to `#87CEEB` - might try and change to a HEX color instead as it seems node.js has trouble interpreting the `skyblue` color. 
You can see the color references here [CSS Colors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that only a part of CSS is not working.

Inspect body tag and check from where it is picking background style.
Include your CSS right after the the CSS file from which background style is currently picked.
My most probable guess is it is picking background style from some other file.

Make sure there is no in-file and inline CSS giving background style.

or use

background: skyblue !important;